# I can't make outlet in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I don't want to make my code messy so I made a separate class for table view cell but when I tried to make outlet of my `UIImageView`, it's showing error

```
import UIKit
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!

}
```

// code of my tableview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    var array = ["apple","blue_graps","cherry","grape","Pineapple","pomegranate","Strawberry"]

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


      return  array.count

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable `image` to some other name, e.g. `myImage` or `icon`.

There is a deprecated property in `UITableViewCell` called `image` and you cannot redeclare it. (It was deprecated in iOS 3 already but it's still there).